# Add a column to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a few columns to a dataframe - here is the code

```py
import import_ipynb
import talib
import numpy
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
import sqlite3
import pandas
import numpy as np
conn = sqlite3.connect('Strategy_RSI_MACD_Data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
 
c.execute("select distinct Stock from Universe")
tickers = c.fetchall()   
for row in tickers:
    if row[0]:
        ticker_list.append(row[0])
        stockdetails = yf.download(
            tickers = ticker_list,
            period = '6mo',
            interval = '1d',
            group_by = 'ticker',
            auto_adjust = False,
            prepost = False,
            threads = True,
            proxy = None
        )

df_ta = pandas.DataFrame(data = stockdetails['Adj Close'], dtype=numpy.float64)
stockdetails['RSI'] = df_ta.apply(lambda c: talib.RSI(c, timeperiod = 14))
```

The last line is throwing this error:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 505, placement implies 1

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the type of ```stockdetails``` before the lastline?

Comment: I think (sorry still learning) "stockdetails = []" will make this a list ?

Comment: you are initializing it as list using []. but ```yf.download``` changes the type of stockdetails

Comment: stockdetails is ok! I think it is when I'm trying to add another column to the dataframe which is causing the crash  stockdetails['RSI'] = df_ta.apply(lambda c: talib.RSI(c, timeperiod = 14))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! - I needed to insert a loop that would loop through the values:

```
for row in tickers:
    c.execute("select [Adj Close] from StockData where Symbol = ? ", (row))
    AdjClose = c.fetchall()
    df_ta = pd.DataFrame(data = AdjClose, dtype=numpy.float64)
    df_ta = df_ta.apply(lambda c: talib.RSI(c, timeperiod = 14))
```

Comment: Does the 'for' loop apply to all four lines?

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function is returning 505 values whereas your assignment should have just one. Try converting the output into a list-

```
stockdetails['RSI'] = [df_ta.apply(lambda c: talib.RSI(c, timeperiod = 14))]
```

Comment: Thank for the response - that change resulted in this error
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `len(stockdetails)`?

Comment: sure - it is 128

Comment: Try: `stockdetails['RSI']= talib.RSI(stockdetails['Adj Close'], timeperiod=14)`

Comment: TypeError: Argument 'real' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got DataFrame)

Comment: `close= pd.Series(stockdetails['Adj Close'])`
`close = close.to_numpy()` `stockdetails['RSI']= talib.RSI(close timeperiod=14)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222080/discussion-between-shradha-and-samb).

Comment: Thanks getting close I think - now I'm getting this error: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().   I believe the error is on this line close= pd.Series(stockdetails['Adj Close'])